# Pegasus RAID *missing* a drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, raid, restore

I have a RAID5 Pegasus R6, connected via Thunderbolt. At some point, it started making strange repetitive beeping noises; when connected, one of the drives wasn't showing up *at all*.

Shortly thereafter, while trying to diagnose this, a *different* drive in the array went actually-DEAD (not missing, like the original one.) So, now my data's MIA; but I only actually have one *dead* drive. I need help getting the Pegasus to ‘see’ the missing drive, so I can begin to rebuild the dead one.

Here's what I see:

[image]

[image]

Notice, drive #3 is missing entirely from the list; and it's got one dark LED on the physical machine, for no apparent reason.

Meanwhile, the command-line gives me the following error (but only for this slot; the rest work):

```
cliib> phydrv -a online -p 3
Error (0x49841602): invalid physical drive id in data buffer
```

Comment: Do you know how I can safely check that without my system trying to mount or otherwise touch the data on the drive?